# Google Analytics Embed API Server Side Authorization not rendering the charts with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, google-oauth

I am trying to render charts using Server Side Authorization in C# but I am not able to do it.

Google has an example but based on Python and I need to build based on C# MVC:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

I have created the Service Account and downloaded the JSON file:

Controler

```
public class StatsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Stats
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var json = "C:\\temp\\client_secrets.json";

        string[] scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }; // Put your scopes here

        var stream = new FileStream(json, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

        try
        {
            Task<string> task = ((ITokenAccess)credential).GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
            task.Wait();
            var bearer = task.Result;

            ViewBag.Token = bearer;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

View

```
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<div id="chart-1-container"></div>

<script>

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  /**
   * Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '{{ @ViewBag.Token }}'
    }
  });


  /**
   * Creates a new DataChart instance showing sessions over the past 30 days.
   * It will be rendered inside an element with the id "chart-1-container".
   */
  var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'ids': 'ga:XXXX', // <-- Replace with the ids value for your view.
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:users',
      'dimensions': 'ga:date'
    },
    chart: {
      'container': 'chart-1-container',
      'type': 'LINE',
      'options': {
        'width': '100%'
      }
    }
  });
  dataChart1.execute();

});
</script>
```

Nothing renders, and I get a diferent Token everytime I refresh the View, and all this erros in the console:

[image]

Detail

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the token being different.   Can you post the full 401 error

Comment: Hi, thanks! Please check the updated question with the detail

Comment: @DaImTo did the printscreen helped you?

Comment: Not really its not the full error message. Try taking the access token and testing it with a Http get in a browser try the MetaData api just tack access_token=yourtoken

Comment: Sorry but how I do that?

Comment: ://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/reference/   try reading this

Comment: But What do You Think about my code? Is this the correct way to generate the Token? I have searched your website but did not find any example with server side authorization to Send the token to the view to generate Google charts.

Comment: I have seen it done with php but I am not a web developer I have never managed to get it working myself. In theory it should be possible.

Comment: The example from google website is not clear about how to generate the token :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got finally get it running, the only thing a had to do (after hours of research) was to remove the {{ }} from access_token: property:

```
    gapi.analytics.ready(function () {

        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            serverAuth: {
                access_token: '@ViewBag.Token'
            }
        });
    });
```

And I can get now a Google Analytics chart with no user's login at all:

[image]

And no any console error.

Comment: I need your help on this..I am trying to do the same thing. but I always have the login required error.

Comment: thanks to you..my damn thing worked..after 2 days..google hates .net. i've been trying to do it with the exact same code that you have..the problem with mine is the email of the service account is not added to the analytics account.

Comment: Yes Sir. I have no clue why it wasn't giving me the right token. I have the almost the same code as you do.then I copied yours and I found out analytics need the service accoutn email.